# ThreadPool.SetMinThreads on Azure Redis

Tags: azure, redis, threadpool

How can i set the minimum number of threads on the Redis Service of azure?

I'm facing recurrent timeouts, and I keep seeing `IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=11,Free=32756,Min=4,Max=32767)`.

Busy being 11 and min being 4 means that for approx 3.5 seconds the queue was stopped w8ing for threads right?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to be done in the application consuming Redis.

For example if you are using ASP.NET, then use the "[minIoThreads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.processmodelsection.miniothreads(v=vs.110).aspx)" configuration setting under the  `<processModel>`  configuration element in machine.config. If you are running inside of Azure WebSites, this setting is not exposed through the configuration options. You should be able to set this programmatically  from your `Application_Start` method in **global.asax.cs**.

See this link for details: https://gist.github.com/JonCole/e65411214030f0d823cb